# pandas pivot_table with dates as values

Tags: pandas, dataframe, pivot-table

let's say I have the following table of customer data

```
df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict({"Customer":[0,0,1], 
        "Date":['01.01.2016', '01.02.2016', '01.01.2016'], 
        "Type":["First Buy", "Second Buy", "First Buy"], 
        "Value":[10,20,10]})
```

which looks like this:

```
Customer |   Date   |   Type   |   Value
-----------------------------------------
       0 |01.01.2016|First Buy |     10 
-----------------------------------------
       0 |01.02.2016|Second Buy|     20 
-----------------------------------------
       1 |01.01.2016|First Buy |     10
```

I want to pivot the table by the Type column.
However, the pivoting only gives the numeric Value columns as a result.
I'd desire a structure like:

```
 Customer | First Buy Date | First Buy Value | Second Buy Date | Second Buy Value
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

where the missing values are NAN or NAT
Is this possible using pivot_table. If not, I can imagine some workarounds, but they are quite lenghty. Any other suggestions?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Use [`unstack`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.unstack.html):

```
df1 = df.set_index(['Customer', 'Type']).unstack()
df1.columns = ['_'.join(cols) for cols in df1.columns]
print (df1)
         Date_First Buy Date_Second Buy  Value_First Buy  Value_Second Buy
Customer                                                                  
0            01.01.2016      01.02.2016             10.0              20.0
1            01.01.2016            None             10.0               NaN
```

If need another order of columns use [`swaplevel`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.MultiIndex.swaplevel.html) and [`sort_index`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.sort_index.html):

```
df1 = df.set_index(['Customer', 'Type']).unstack()

df1.columns = ['_'.join(cols) for cols in df1.columns.swaplevel(0,1)]
df1.sort_index(axis=1, inplace=True)
print (df1)
         First Buy_Date  First Buy_Value Second Buy_Date  Second Buy_Value
Customer                                                                  
0            01.01.2016             10.0      01.02.2016              20.0
1            01.01.2016             10.0            None               NaN
```

Comment: Wow, really beautiful. The indexing features together with stacking are very neat.

Comment: To rename the columns, is it possible to rename the columns using method chaining?

Comment: sorry, I don't understand what you mean? I think method chaining could work using .pipe, a lambda function and either of your list comprehensions. Wondering if rename or rename_axis could work here, too

Comment: Do you need `df1.rename(columns={'First Buy_Date': 'another_col1', 'Second Buy_Date': 'another_col2'})` ?

Comment: I think this might work, though it will get tedious for lots of columns. However, the dict, might be generated from your list comprehension. My first attempt at piping failed, since you can't assign inside a lambda function. However, many thanks

Comment: Another solution can be replace values in column `Type` before `unstack` - `df['Type'] = df.Type.map({'First Buy': 'a', 'Second Buy': 'b'})`, but need all values in `dict`, else you get `NaN`.

Comment: I see, and also how this works when chaining. I just want to clearify my previous comment: Your naming scheme would work perfectly, particularly since there are many columns in my use case

Comment: Hmmm, if in column names is no pattern, you need use all column names, you are right.

Comment: @jezrael here is your solution as an obnoxious one liner with chaining.  `df.set_index(['Customer', 'Type']).unstack().sort_index(1, 1).T.set_index(df.set_index(['Customer', 'Type']).unstack().sort_index(1, 1).columns.to_series().str[::-1].str.join('_')).T`

Comment: wau, it is crazy ;) Thank you @piRSquared